# Symfony 6: create action route with dynamic parts

Tags: symfony, symfony6, symfony-routing

I have a controller action in my project based on Symfony 6.3:

```php
#[Route('/test')]
class TestController extends AbstractController
{
    #[Route('/events/page/{page<\d+>?1}/itemsPerPage/{itemsPerPage<\d+>?10}', name: 'get_events')]
    public function getEvents(PaginatorInterface $paginator, int $page = 1, int $itemsPerPage = 10)
    {
    // ...
    }
}
```

This action uses [KnpPaginatorBundle](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpPaginatorBundle) to paginate found events, that's why I need `page` and `itemsPerPage` parameters.
Everything works fine, when I call my action this way:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/test/events/page/1/itemsPerPage/7
```

What I want is to make `/page/` and `/itemsPerPage/` URL parts dynamic too. What I mean:

- if I omit `itemsPerPage` parameter (`http://127.0.0.1:8080/test/events/page/1`), route should stay valid and use default `itemsPerPage` value (`10`). Notice, that there is not only `7` is absent in URL, but the whole part - `/itemsPerPage/7` (dynamic `7` and "static" `/itemsPerPage/`);
- if I omit `page` parameter (`http://127.0.0.1:8080/test/events/itemsPerPage/7`), route should stay valid and use default `page` value (`1`). Notice, that there is not only `1` is absent in URL, but the whole part - `/page/1` (dynamic `1` and "static" `/page/`);
- `http://127.0.0.1:8080/test/events/page/1/itemsPerPage/7` should still stay valid (passing both parameters).

I realize, that it could be easier to refuse "static" parts usage and do this:

```php
#[Route('/events/{page<\d+>?1}/{itemsPerPage<\d+>?10}', name: 'get_events')]
```

But I plan to add much more GET parameters in future, so I wouldn't like my URL to finally look like `http://127.0.0.1:8080/test/events/1/7/100/8648/78978/...` (unless this is the only possible solution).

Also I could try to do something like this to cover all possible cases:

```php
#[Route('/events/page/{page<\d+>?1}/itemsPerPage/{itemsPerPage<\d+>?10}')]
#[Route('/events/itemsPerPage/{itemsPerPage<\d+>?10}/page/{page<\d+>?1}')]
#[Route('/events/itemsPerPage/{itemsPerPage<\d+>?10}')]
#[Route('/events/page/{page<\d+>?1}')]
```

But as I said above, additional GET parameter will occur later, so such combinations isn't an option because of a huge number of possible cases.

Does Symfony provide a possibility to handle such situation?

Answer (score 0):

At the Route I would only add variables that the page cannot work without.
For example if a page lists user events, then I would add user_id at the Route.
Everything else you can get from `knp_paginator configuration yaml` or `get` or `session`
and handle them in the controller.

In your current case I would use `$_GET` to store `page` and `itemsPerPage` in session variables
and then access them from the session, validate them and then pass them like this:

```
    $pagination = $paginator->paginate(
        $queryBuilder, /* query NOT result */
        $page,
        $itemsPerPage
    );
```

This way you can have a clean url and the flexibility to add more parameters in the future.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But my goal is to read `page` and `itemsPerPage` directly from route arguments, without complications with session. I just want to know, is it possible to make static parts of the route as dynamic. Regarding `user_id` - I don't need it, 'cause my project is an API, where JWT login is implemented.

Comment: @Boolean_Type : I see... (user_id was just an example to distinguish between required and optional params.) Maybe passing an `array` or an `object` would work better in your case? Still if the user views an event and then returns back to the events list, you would need a session var to remember the page number...

Comment: No session and nothing to remember, it is REST API, not standard site with pages and views. My question is about totally different think - about possibility in Symfony routing.

Comment: @Boolean_Type: yea, in this case my answer is not very relevant... do not have much experience there, i could only suggest to have a look on how https://api-platform.com/ works if you have not already done that. Maybe this is not entirely a symfony thing...